# Laravel 5 different ads types

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working on classifieds site and I will have different types of ads. There will be cars, real estate and so on. All types will have type specific attributes. For example, realestate ads will have square meter attribute which cars doesnt need.

I created database model for that situation but have no idea how to tell that relations to eloquent. Also are there any better approach to this problem?

Ad table
-id
-date
-ad_type_id

Cars table
-id
-title
-horse_power

Realestate table
-id
-title
-squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Polymorphic Relations".

If you follow the example at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations and simply replace your tables with theirs with something like this...

```
cars
    id - integer
    title - string
    horse_power - integer

realestates
    id - integer
    title - string
    squares - integer

ads
    id - integer
    description - text
    adable_id - integer
    adable_type - string
```

You'l be able to do what you want. So you would only need to do

```
$ads = Ad::with('adable')->get()
```

that would then be a collection of all ads (with cars and realestates). then you would want to create 3 blades, something like

```
ad_list.blade.php
ad_car.blade.php
ad_realestate.blade.php
```

In your ads_list view you would have something like

```
@foreach ($ads as $ad)
  @include('ad_'.snakecase(classbasename($ad->adable_type)))
@endforeach
```

then in `ad_car` and `ad_realestate` format the content how you want

```
//car view
$ad->adable->title
$ad->adable->horse_power
```

It's a weird concept and it took me a few tries to get it right. I found https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/10 helpful in explaining the concept of showing polymorphic relations in different views (starts around 8:30). Give that a look over if you get confused.